# Terminal inside Electron application like visual studio code editor

Tags: node.js, electron

Requirement is to embed a terminal in Electron app wherein all commands which I can run from bash can be run in the embedded terminal too like vs-code editor.

Suppose I want to 'npm install' I want it to be possible through my embedded terminal too. Could anyone suggest possible solutions ?

Comment: yeah i have heard about few like xterm and hyper but it is giving some errors.can you please name that some packages?

Comment: I am talking about my own electron app. i don't want to add terminal in atom.

Comment: Oh sorry, I can't believe I read "electron" as atom.

Comment: VS Code is using [xterm.js](https://xtermjs.org/), which is a npm package you can install. Have a look at that...

Comment: Yes,but the xterm.js just prints the output but not it works like terminal that means read and write

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I connect xterm.js(in electron) to a real working command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63390143/how-do-i-connect-xterm-jsin-electron-to-a-real-working-command-prompt)