# How do I connect xterm.js(in electron) to a real working command prompt?

Tags: electron, command-prompt, xtermjs

I've dug myself into a deep rabbit hole trying to find out what the title says. If you're confused about what this question is, I'll give a more detailed explanation: Have you ever seen the VSCode Terminal? or Terminus? Well I want to do what those applications do. I have an electron app, and for the users convenience I want to include a command prompt of some sorts into it. I've looked in to xterm.js, but I can only find examples of things like SSH, not a direct link to a console hosted on the system. **What I'm asking is how do I connect xterm.js(in electron) to a real working command prompt?** I've seen programs able to interact with cmd.exe such as Windows Terminal. I'll use it as an example.

[Image taken from process hacker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgldw.png)

In the attached photo you can see three processes. WindowsTerminal.exe, OpenConsole.exe, and cmd.exe. After digging around in the source code of Windows Terminal, I can see the OpenConsole.exe gets started with every instance of a cmd that you make. So I assume that is the program that's interacting with cmd.exe. Now I know that Windows Terminal is made using UWP but you can see similar things happening [with VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QENMu.png)(I opened a bunch of terminals to demonstrate)

here is another post with a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61034778/command-prompt-in-electron), but with no answers. I hope this one gains some traction.

So if you can answer, thanks. If you got sidetracked a bit, remember my question: **How do I connect xterm.js(in electron) to a real working command prompt?**

Sorry if you couldn't understand my wording, im not very good at this :P

Comment: Update for anyone interested: I found an npm package called node-pty and I think I'm getting somewhere

Comment: Is there a tutorial for this for a web app?

Comment: @zero_cool A web app is quite different from an electron app because web apps don't have access to node.js apis which is what allows this to work. Your best bet for getting a terminal to work in the web browser is with an ssh connection or manually transmitting packets with websockets to a remote server

Comment: It's definitely possible for a web app to be able to make requests to a node API. Is there a different type of access that's required. If I run a node server on one port, I can make requests to that port from the UI of the webapp (clicking a submit button etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, code on github: https://github.com/77Z/electron-local-terminal-prototype

Comment: Is there a web app gist somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

The [following video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vhDBbbMJWoY) was helpful for me. Shortly, you need to :

1. install node-pty and electron-rebuild packages *(additional to the xterm)*
2. Place the following codes to appropriate process files

In the main process *(main.js)*:

```js
const os = require('os');
const pty = require('node-pty');

var shell = os.platform() === "win32" ? "powershell.exe" : "bash";
var ptyProcess = pty.spawn(shell, [], {
        name: 'xterm-color',
        cols: 80,
        rows: 24,
        cwd: process.env.HOME,
        env: process.env
    });
    
    ptyProcess.on("data", (data) => {
      mainWindow.webContents.send("terminal-incData", data);
    });

    ipcMain.on("terminal-into", (event, data)=> {
      ptyProcess.write(data);
    })
```

In the renderer process:

```js
const Terminal  =  require('xterm').Terminal;
const FitAddon = require('xterm-addon-fit').FitAddon;

const term = new Terminal();
const fitAddon = new FitAddon();
term.loadAddon(fitAddon);

// Open the terminal in #terminal-container
term.open(document.getElementById('terminal-container'));
term.onData(e => {
    ipcRenderer.send("terminal-into", e);
} );
ipcRenderer.on('terminal-incData', (event, data) => {
    term.write(data);
})

// Make the terminal's size and geometry fit the size of #terminal-container
fitAddon.fit();
```

3. run electron-rebuild command if you get an error.

You might get the following errors when you try to install electron-rebuild package:

- [Solution](https://github.com/microsoft/node-pty/issues/441) for MAC: `error:  no template named 'remove_cv_t'`.
- [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59470406/how-to-solve-could-not-find-any-python-installation-to-use-with-docker-node-al) for Windows: `gyp ERR! find Python`

Comment: Well this is... Interesting, that video that helped you was my video that I made after finding the solution, I do however appreciate the time you put in to this post, the solutions for common errors, and the xterm terminal fit add-on. Thanks anyways.

Comment: lol, then thank you. Your video was really helpful. Good luck to your YouTube Channel.

Comment: I did everything but conpty.node seems to be compiled using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 98 and it requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 99. electron-build doesn't help with this

Comment: A similar error occurs on the prototype you've supplied too.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while trying to run the prototype:

> ```
> A JavaScript error occurred in the main process Uncaught Exception: Error: The module '/home/xyz/Downloads/electron-local-terminal-prototype-master/node_modules/node-pty/build/Release/pty.node' was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 80. Please try re-compiling or re-installing the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`). at process.func [as dlopen] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140:31) at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1034:18) at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140:31) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32) at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14) at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:769:28)  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19) at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18) at Object. <anonymous> (/home/xyz/Downloads/electron-local-terminal-prototype-master/node_modules/node-pty/lib/unixTerminal.js:26:11) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:30) enter code here
> ```

I had to rebuild node following this answer to get it working:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52796884